# AppBundle\Entity\Goeder could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to open "bestelling/alle" and then I am getting this error;
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Goeder could not be converted to string.
But I don't where this is coming from. I will link all the used entities and controllers.

Entity Goeder

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * Goeder
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="goeder")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\GoederRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"bestelordernummer"}, message="Dit bestelordernummer bestaat al!")
 */
class Goeder
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="naamleverancier", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $naamleverancier;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="bestelordernummer", type="integer", unique=true)
     */
    private $bestelordernummer;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="omschrijving", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $omschrijving;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hoeveelheidbesteld", type="integer")
     */
    private $hoeveelheidbesteld;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="artikelnummer", type="integer")
     */
    private $artikelnummer;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="datumontvangst", type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $datumontvangst;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="kwaliteit", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $kwaliteit;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hoeveelheidontvangen", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $hoeveelheidontvangen;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Keuringseis", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $keuringseis;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="zendingsnummer", type="integer", unique=true, nullable=true)
     */
    private $zendingsnummer;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="locatie", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $locatie;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bestelregel", mappedBy = "bestelling")
    */
    private $bestelregels;

    /**
     * Set naamleverancier
     *
     * @param string $naamleverancier
     *
     * @return Goeder
     */
    public function setNaamleverancier($naamleverancier)
    {
        $this->naamleverancier = $naamleverancier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get naamleverancier
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNaamleverancier()
    {
        return $this->naamleverancier;
    }

    /**
     * Set bestelordernummer
     *
     * @param integer $bestelordernummer
     *
     * @return Goeder
     */
    public function setBestelordernummer($bestelordernummer)
    {
        $this->bestelordernummer = $bestelordernummer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bestelordernummer
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getBestelordernummer()
    {
        return $this->bestelordernummer;
    }

    /**
     * Set omschrijving
     *
     * @param string $omschrijving
     *
     * @return Goeder
     */
    public function setOmschrijving($omschrijving)
    {
        $this->omschrijving = $omschrijving;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get omschrijving
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOmschrijving()
    {
        return $this->omschrijving;
    }

    /**
     * Set hoeveelheidbesteld
     *
     * @param integer $hoeveelheidbesteld
     *
     * @return Goeder
     */
    public function setHoeveelheidbesteld($hoeveelheidbesteld)
    {
        $this->hoeveelheidbesteld = $hoeveelheidbesteld;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get hoeveelheidbesteld
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getHoeveelheidbesteld()
    {
        return $this->hoeveelheidbesteld;
    }

    /**
     * Set datumontvangst
     *
     * @param \DateTime $datumontvangst
     *
     * @return Goeder
     */
    public function setDatumontvangst($datumontvangst)
    {
        $this->datumontvangst = $datumontvangst;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get datumontvangst
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDatumontvangst()
    {
        return $this->datumontvangst;
    }

    /**
     * Set kwaliteit
     *
     * @param integer $kwaliteit
     *
     * @return Goeder
     */
    public function setKwaliteit($kwaliteit)
    {
        $this->kwaliteit = $kwaliteit;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get kwaliteit
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getKwaliteit()
    {
        return $this->kwaliteit;
    }

    /**
     * Set hoeveelheidontvangen
     *
     * @param integer $hoeveelheidontvangen
     *
     * @return Goeder
     */
    public function setHoeveelheidontvangen($hoeveelheidontvangen)
    {
        $this->hoeveelheidontvangen = $hoeveelheidontvangen;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get hoeveelheidontvangen
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getHoeveelheidontvangen()
    {
        return $this->hoeveelheidontvangen;
    }

    /**
     * Set artikelnummer
     *
     * @param integer $artikelnummer
     *
     * @return Goeder
     */
    public function setArtikelnummer($artikelnummer)
    {
        $this->artikelnummer = $artikelnummer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get artikelnummer
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getArtikelnummer()
    {
        return $this->artikelnummer;
    }

    /**
     * Set keuringseis
     *
     * @param integer $keuringseis
     *
     * @return Goeder
     */
    public function setKeuringseis($keuringseis)
    {
        $this->keuringseis = $keuringseis;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get keuringseis
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getKeuringseis()
    {
        return $this->keuringseis;
    }

    /**
     * Set zendingsnummer
     *
     * @param integer $zendingsnummer
     *
     * @return Goeder
     */
    public function setZendingsnummer($zendingsnummer)
    {
        $this->zendingsnummer = $zendingsnummer;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get zendingsnummer
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getZendingsnummer()
    {
        return $this->zendingsnummer;
    }

    /**
     * Set locatie
     *
     * @param integer $locatie
     *
     * @return Goeder
     */
    public function setLocatie($locatie)
    {
        $this->locatie = $locatie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get locatie
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getLocatie()
    {
        return $this->locatie;
    }
    /**
     * Set bestelregels
     *
     * @param string $bestelregels
     *
     * @return Goeder
     */
    public function setBestelregels($bestelregels)
    {
        $this->bestelregels = $bestelregels;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bestelregels
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBestelregels()
    {
        return $this->bestelregels;
    }
}
```

Entity Bestelregel

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Bestelregel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="bestelregel")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\BestelregelRepository")
 */
class Bestelregel
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artikel", inversedBy="bestelregels")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Artikelnummer", referencedColumnName="Artikelnummer")
     */
    private $artikel;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Goeder", inversedBy="bestelregels")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bestelordernummer", referencedColumnName="bestelordernummer")
     */
    private $bestelling;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="bestelhoeveelheid", type="integer")
     */
    private $bestelhoeveelheid;

     /**
     * Set id
     *
     * @param integer $id
     *
     * @return Bestelregel
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    /**
     * Set artikel
     * @param string $artikel
     * @return Bestelregel
     */
    public function setArtikel($artikel)
    {
        $this->artikel = $artikel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get artikel
    * @return string
    */
    public function getArtikel(){
    return $this->artikel;
    }
    public function __toString(){
    return $this->getArtikel();
    }

    /**
     * Set bestelling
     * @param string $bestelling
     * @return Bestelregel
     */
    public function setBestelling($bestelling)
    {
        $this->bestelling = $bestelling;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get bestelling
    * @return string
    */
    public function getBestelling(){
    return $this->bestelling;
    }
    public function Bestelling__toString(){
    return $this->getBestelling();
    }

    /**
     * Set bestelhoeveelheid
     *
     * @param integer $bestelhoeveelheid
     *
     * @return Bestelregel
     */
    public function setBestelhoeveelheid($bestelhoeveelheid)
    {
        $this->bestelhoeveelheid = $bestelhoeveelheid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get bestelhoeveelheid
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getBestelhoeveelheid()
    {
        return $this->bestelhoeveelheid;
    }

}
```

This is the  Bestelregel controller

```
<?php
    namespace AppBundle\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

    use AppBundle\Entity\Bestelregel;
    use AppBundle\Form\Type\BestelregelType;

    class BestelregelController extends Controller
    {
    //Route om nieuw Artikel aan te maken
    /**
    * @Route("/bestelregel/nieuw", name="nieuwebestelregel")
    */
    public function nieuweBestelregel(Request $request) {
    $nieuweBestelregel = new Bestelregel();
    $form = $this->createForm(BestelregelType::class, $nieuweBestelregel);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($nieuweBestelregel);
            $em->flush() ;
        return $this->redirect($this->generateurl("nieuwebestelregel")) ;
        }
    return new Response($this->renderView('form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView())));
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/bestelregel/alle", name="allebestelregels")
    */
    Public function alleBestelregel(Request $request) {
    $bestelregels = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Bestelregel")->findAll();
    return new Response($this->renderView('bestelregel.html.twig', array('bestelregels' => $bestelregels)));
    }

    }
```

Bestelregel twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
        {% block body %}
            <h1>Overzicht Bestelregels</h1>
            <ul>
            {% for bestelregel in bestelregels %}
                    <li style="color:darkgreen; float:left"> 
                        Id: {{bestelregel.id}} <br>
                        Bestelordernummer: {{bestelregel.bestelling}} <br>
                        Artikelnummer: {{bestelregel.artikel}} <br>
                        Bestelde hoeveelheid: {{bestelregel.bestelhoeveelheid}} <br>

                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            <ul>
        {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Try to use __toString method

Comment: They are there in Bestelling Entity

Comment: It's `Bestelordernummer: {{bestelregel.bestelling}} <br>` in your Twig template. `bestelregel.bestelling` is a `Goeder`-Object. You probably mean `Bestelordernummer: {{bestelregel.bestelling.bestelordernummer}} <br>`. Same for the Artikel-Row afterwards.

Comment: that worked, thanks!

Comment: Please post the correct solution as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Try add _toString() method to you object:

```
/**
 * (Add this method into your class)
 *
 * @return string String representation of this class
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```